# Using VisualBrush as OpacityMask

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visualbrush

I want to set `OpacityMask` to a control, but I need to build that mask dynamically.
Here is how it should look:

[image]

The width and height of the whole (red) rectangle is dynamic, based on width and height of parent control. But I need to place two small rectangles (static width and height) in top left and top right corner, as shown on image. So how can I make this happen?

I tried this code, but it doesn't work: (nothing is displayed at all)

```
<Border BorderBrush="#80FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
    <Border.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <DockPanel>
                    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="2">
                        <Border Background="Transparent" Width="12" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <Border Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <Border Background="Transparent" Width="12" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Border Background="Black" />
                </DockPanel>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Border.OpacityMask>
</Border>
```

Is it even valid to use `VisualBrush` this way (as a `OpacityMask`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want those Black squares in you image to be transparent?

**Update**: Uploaded sample project here: http://www.mediafire.com/?5tfkd1cxwfq0rct

I think the problem is that the `Panel` inside the `VisualBrush` won't stretch. You could get the desired effect by Binding the Width and Height of whatever `Panel` you use to the ActualWidth and ActualHeight of the `Border`

```
<Border Name="border" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
    <Border.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=border, Path=ActualWidth}"
                      Height="{Binding ElementName=border, Path=ActualHeight}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
                </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Border.OpacityMask>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Testing OpacityMask with a rather long string................." Grid.ZIndex="3"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Green"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

**Update Again**
The DropShadowEffect for the Decorator Child of the `Border` seems to push the OpacityMask for the `Border` both Verticaly and Horizontaly. And what's even worse is that it seems to stack, so in your example when you have three DropShadowEffects for three nested `Decorators`, the sum of the BlurRadius is 45 (20+15+10) so the OpacityMask is pushed by a value of 45 (at least it looks like this is whats going on, but it's a little hard to tell..). You could try to compensate for this by increasing the ColumnDefinition Widths and RowDefinition Heights but I think it'll be hard to find a dynamic solution.

A better approach to your problem may be to use `Border.Clip` but that doesn't come easy either.

```
Point1:  0, 2
Point2: 12, 2
Point3: 12, 0
Point4: Width of Border - 12, 0
Point5: Width of Border - 12, 2
Point5: Width of Border, 2
Point6: Width of Border, Height of Border
Point7: 0, Height of Border
```

**Update 3**
Came up with a better solution that doesn't require so many Bindings. Create a custom class that derives from `Border` and override GetLayoutClip. This works both in Designer and Runtime. To increase flexibility of `ClippedBorder` you could introduce some Dependency Properties to use instead of the hardcoded 2 and 12. New sample app here: http://www.mediafire.com/?9i13rrqpbmzdbvs

```
public class ClippedBorder : Border
{
    protected override Geometry GetLayoutClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
    {
        PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        pathGeometry.Figures = new PathFigureCollection();

        //Point1:  0, 2
        PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();
        pathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(0, 2);

        //Point2: 12, 2
        LineSegment lineSegment1 = new LineSegment();
        lineSegment1.Point = new Point(12, 2);

        //Point3: 12, 0
        LineSegment lineSegment2 = new LineSegment();
        lineSegment2.Point = new Point(12, 0);

        //Point4: Width of Border - 12, 0
        LineSegment lineSegment3 = new LineSegment();
        lineSegment3.Point = new Point(this.ActualWidth-12, 0);

        //Point5: Width of Border - 12, 2
        LineSegment lineSegment4 = new LineSegment();
        lineSegment4.Point = new Point(this.ActualWidth-12, 2);

        //Point5: Width of Border, 2
        LineSegment lineSegment5 = new LineSegment();
        lineSegment5.Point = new Point(this.ActualWidth, 2);

        //Point6: Width of Border, Height of Border
        LineSegment lineSegment6 = new LineSegment();
        lineSegment6.Point = new Point(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight);

        //Point7: 0, Height of Border 
        LineSegment lineSegment7 = new LineSegment();
        lineSegment7.Point = new Point(0, this.ActualHeight);

        pathFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment1);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment2);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment3);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment4);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment5);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment6);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment7);

        pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);

        return pathGeometry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the black squares are supposed to be transparent. I tried your code and it doesn't work - it shows everything. I tried to increase Width/Height on Rows/Columns and it still shows the content.

Comment: @Paja: Ok, I uploaded my sample project which seems to be working. Try it out and let me know what the differences may be

Comment: @Paja: Just checking, did you set `Name="border"` for the `Border`?

Comment: Yeah you are right, it works. But I can't make it working in my program. :-( It works when the Border doesn't have any additional content. Once I insert Grid with some elements, the OpacityMask will be ignored. Shouldn't have the OpacityMask effect on child elements as well?

Comment: @Paja: I'm unable to reproduce your problem and you're right, it should work on the Child element as well. I inserted a `Grid` with some Children and it's still working. See my updated example. Code you post some sample code reproducing your problem?

Comment: @Meleak: So I was able to isolate the problem. http://www.mediafire.com/?kvafskkqdalls14 Here you can download the project. When I use 3 nested Decorators with DropShadowEffect, then the OpacityMask stops working for some reason. It even seems like the OpacityMask is translated and scaled.

Comment: @Paja: That's a really weird problem you found.. In that scenario it doesn't look like it's possible to use OpacityMask. I uploaded a new sample app that uses `Border.Clip` instead, see my updated answer

Comment: @Meleak: Thanks, will check the code right away. So is this some kind of a bug in WPF? Or why does it behave in such a way?

Comment: @Paja: I'm not sure whether this is a bug or a feature.. I doesn't seem very user-friendly though as it's extremely hard to predict the end-result. I'd call it a bug

Comment: @Paja: Came up with a better solution for Clip, see **Update 3**

Comment: @Meleak: Thanks! Now it finally works. I still don't get it why the DropShadowEffect behaves like that, though.