# Make border gap using Opacity Mask

Tags: wpf, opacitymask

What i need to achieve :

[image]

what i have :

[image]

I need to some how create a gap , iv'e tried using something like the BorderGapMaskConverter from the GroupBox template but i can't seem to figure out how to position it ( for starters i would like to apply the opacity mask for all tab items .

My TabControl Template : (Shortend xaml)  , Below iv'e created a test opacity mask which i would attempt to show only a small part of my TabControl  by assigning an opacity mask containing a visual brush containing this rectangle as it's visual (**THIS IS JUST A FAILED  ATTEMPT TO TRY TO UNDERSTAND HOW TO APPLY AN OPACITY MASK** ):

```
  <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" Fill="Black" />
```

for starters i would like to know why this does not work ..

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
  <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition  Width="0"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <TabPanel Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
         <Border>
             <Border.OpacityMask>
                  <VisualBrush>
                      <VisualBrush.Visual>
                           <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5" Fill="Black" />
                       </VisualBrush.Visual>
                   </VisualBrush>
              </Border.OpacityMask>
              <ContentPresenter/>
       </Border>
    </Grid>
```

2) Secondly, The real question , any ideas how to achieve the effect described in the pictures  ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981696/using-visualbrush-as-opacitymask 

This is setting me on the right track .

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do that with the `Border` properties?:

```
<Border Height="76" Padding="25,0" BorderBrush="Cyan" BorderThickness="1,6,1,0">
    <ContentPresenter />
</Border>
```

Comment: i don't see how this would produce gaps in the top border of the tab control , under the tabitems or as to my more specific need under the selected TabItem , look at the link i posted in the comment above .

Comment: I've actually  found my answer i'll post it tomorrow , though i would like a simpler solution to this issue .

Comment: Apologies, I must have misunderstood what gap you're talking about.

Comment: I've actually made a great solution for this matter , it's real close the the implementation in the GroupBox template , i'll post it later i just have a small problem there , thanks any ways.